# iOS app crashes while synthesising audio: buffer, frames <unavailable>

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, audio, typedef

I’m synthesising audio on an iPhone using additive synthesis and my app, written in Objective C, crashes while playing audio. The synthesis engine worked in a previous version of the app and with an earlier iOS. I'm currently testing it for iOS 10.3.3 using Xcode 8.3.3.

---

EDIT - in the current version, the view controller sends MIDI note on messages to communicate with the synthesis engine. The previous version did not use MIDI commands.

---

The app synthesises two sounds: a bell and a chorus of sine tones. It does this smoothly and without transients. However it will crash if one sound is playing while attempting to play the other. Yet it never crashes if the same sound is repeated or if the user stops the chorus sound before playing the bell sound (or vice versa).

The bell tone has 11 partials of fixed frequency, each partial shaped by an amplitude envelope. The chorus tone has 5 partials each with a pitch shift envelope and an amplitude envelope. Envelope duration is calculated at runtime from when a user triggers a sound until the end of the last active state, as shown in the diagram (*below*).

The crash happens consistently under two conditions.

Firstly, a crash can be caused by *playing a bell while a chorus sound is still playing*, in which case Xcode goes into debug looking for `Amplitude partial 6,` a partial that would not be used if the buffer was still trying to access a chorus sound which only has *5 partials*.

The diagram shows what should happen if two sound events played in the first state (between 0:00 and 0:24) are followed by a third sound played in the following state. The envelope duration of all three is calculated to end at 1:36. Normally, the bell sound (between 0:24 and 0:48) would last until 1:36, unless a player interrupts it by playing another sound as happens with the previous two sounds. However, being the first sound played in a new state, playing it sends the app into debug.

[image]

Alternately, a crash can also be caused by *playing a chorus sound while a bell is still playing*, in which Xcode goes into debug looking at `Pitch shift partial 1,` a partial that would never be used if the buffer was still trying to access a bell sound where pitch is *fixed*.

In both examples, it looks as if my code fails when it tries to access a buffer that was active prior to the change of state. But I can't find the reason. I tried changing the buffer size but that made little difference (it just happened to be set to 5 when I produced the logs below).

Below are two methods I use to service buffer input for bell and chorus synthesis, the `typedef` that defines buffer states and a debug log for a typical bell crash and chorus crash. I need some feedback on these before diving into the routine where audio is synthesised into the output buffer. I'm happy to share that too but hopefully the problem might already be obvious for someone else.

The app almost works but for the past few weeks I’ve broken the code and fixed it several times without getting closer to solving this problem.

*My code is an extension of an extremely helpful* `AudioBufferPlayer` *and* `Synth` *example created by [Mattias Hollejman](https://github.com/hollance) and refined by [Mario Diana](https://github.com/software-mariodiana/AudioBufferPlayer/wiki/Replacing-C-functions-deprecated-in-iOS-7).*

---

UPDATE

I added a new method called `showPark` to produce a clearer log showing the state of the audio buffer as each live event arrives. When audio buffer size is 3, the log clearly shows the buffer filling after three events leaving no where to go for all subsequent events.

The problem is not evident in the first 24 seconds because the synthesis parameters remain the same. However after 24 seconds, when event 6 happens, things change and the synthesis engine cannot access parameters it needs to synthesise a bell sound. I think this explains how the crash happens. On that basis I'm trying to work out the best way to fix the problem and I welcome any suggestions from anyone who knows what to do.

Here is a crash log.

**crash log (latest)**

```
2017-08-01 13:48:59.330 SatGam2[1169:1226966] PlayView loaded (selectedFamily:1 selectedPlayerID:9)
2017-08-01 13:48:59.331 SatGam2[1169:1226966] ENABLED (player 9: state 0)
2017-08-01 13:49:01.071 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 

2017-08-01 13:49:01.072 SatGam2[1169:1226966] EVENT 1
2017-08-01 13:49:01.072 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:01.072 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status:   0  MIDI Note:   0  State: ToneEventStateInactive
2017-08-01 13:49:01.073 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status:   0  MIDI Note:   0  State: ToneEventStateInactive
2017-08-01 13:49:01.073 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status:   0  MIDI Note:   0  State: ToneEventStateInactive
2017-08-01 13:49:01.073 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          update parkPointer [1]
2017-08-01 13:49:01.073 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:01.074 SatGam2[1169:1226966] Risset Chorus playing MIDI note number: 1 length: 95
2017-08-01 13:49:01.074 SatGam2[1169:1226966] [playChorus - buffer: 0 state: 0]

2017-08-01 13:49:03.873 SatGam2[1169:1226966] EVENT 2
2017-08-01 13:49:03.874 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:03.874 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   1  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:03.874 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status:   0  MIDI Note:   0  State: ToneEventStateInactive
2017-08-01 13:49:03.875 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status:   0  MIDI Note:   0  State: ToneEventStateInactive
2017-08-01 13:49:03.875 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          update parkPointer [2]
2017-08-01 13:49:03.875 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:03.875 SatGam2[1169:1226966] Risset Chorus playing MIDI note number: 3 length: 92
2017-08-01 13:49:03.876 SatGam2[1169:1226966] [playChorus - buffer: 1 state: 0]

2017-08-01 13:49:06.180 SatGam2[1169:1226966] EVENT 3
2017-08-01 13:49:06.180 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:06.180 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   1  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:06.180 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   3  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:06.181 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status:   0  MIDI Note:   0  State: ToneEventStateInactive
2017-08-01 13:49:06.181 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          update parkPointer [0]
2017-08-01 13:49:06.181 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:06.181 SatGam2[1169:1226966] Risset Chorus playing MIDI note number: 5 length: 90
2017-08-01 13:49:06.182 SatGam2[1169:1226966] [playChorus - buffer: 2 state: 0]

2017-08-01 13:49:10.162 SatGam2[1169:1226966] EVENT 4
2017-08-01 13:49:10.162 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:10.163 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   1  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:10.163 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   3  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:10.163 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   5  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:10.163 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          update parkPointer [1]
2017-08-01 13:49:10.163 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:10.164 SatGam2[1169:1226966] Risset Chorus playing MIDI note number: 7 length: 86
2017-08-01 13:49:11.352361+1000 SatGam2[1169:1228409] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0
2017-08-01 13:49:13.041 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 

2017-08-01 13:49:13.042 SatGam2[1169:1226966] EVENT 5
2017-08-01 13:49:13.043 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:13.043 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   1  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:13.043 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   3  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:13.043 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   5  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:13.044 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          update parkPointer [2]
2017-08-01 13:49:13.044 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:13.044 SatGam2[1169:1226966] Risset Chorus playing MIDI note number: 9 length: 83

2017-08-01 13:49:23.332 SatGam2[1169:1226966] ENABLED (player 9: state 1)

2017-08-01 13:49:25.228 SatGam2[1169:1226966] EVENT 6
2017-08-01 13:49:25.228 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:25.229 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   1  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:25.229 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   3  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:25.229 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          MIDI Status: 144  MIDI Note:   5  State: ToneEventStatePressed
2017-08-01 13:49:25.229 SatGam2[1169:1226966]          update parkPointer [0]
2017-08-01 13:49:25.229 SatGam2[1169:1226966] 
2017-08-01 13:49:25.230 SatGam2[1169:1226966] Risset Bell playing MIDI note number: 0 length: 71
SatGam2 was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
(lldb) bt
* thread #9, name = 'com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xb174)
* frame #0: 0x000a1ea5 SatGam2`-[Synth amplitudeLookupPartial6:](self=<unavailable>, _cmd="amplitudeLookupPartial6:", n=<unavailable>) at Synth.m:988 [opt]
    frame #1: 0x000a1519 SatGam2`-[Synth fillBuffer:frames:](self=0x7a831a00, _cmd="fillBuffer:frames:", buffer=<unavailable>, frames=<unavailable>) at Synth.m:805 [opt]
    frame #2: 0x000a516c SatGam2`__39-[PlayViewController startAudioSession]_block_invoke((null)=0x7ce7f8e0, buffer=<unavailable>, audioFormat=AudioStreamBasicDescription @ 0xb0422ab8) at PlayViewController.m:397 [opt]
    frame #3: 0x000a3aa8 SatGam2`PlayCallback(inUserData=0x7946f4c0, inAudioQueue=<unavailable>, inBuffer=<unavailable>) at AudioBufferPlayer.m:30 [opt]
```

*(the rest of the log is the same as logs shown below)*

Here is the code for the new method

```
- (void)showPark:(uint8_t)midiStatus data1:(uint8_t)mapped_MIDINoteNumber
{
    // see if MIDI events are currently active and what kind of event

    eventCount++;

    NSLog(@"\n\n");
    NSLog(@"EVENT %i", eventCount);
    NSLog(@"\n");

    for (int n = 0; n < MaxToneEvents; ++n)
    {
    // scan buffers
        int a    = _tones[n].state;
        int b    = _tones[n].midiStatus;
        int c    = _tones[n].midiNote;

        NSLog(@"         MIDI Status: %3d  MIDI Note: %3d  State: %@", b, c, [self getCurrent:(int)a]);
    }

    // update parkPointer

    parkPointer  = (parkPointer + 1) % MaxToneEvents;
    NSLog(@"         update parkPointer [%i]", parkPointer);
    NSLog(@"\n");
}


    -(NSString *)getCurrent:(int)state
    {
        switch(state){
            case ToneEventStateInactive:
                return @"ToneEventStateInactive";
            case ToneEventStatePressed:
                return @"ToneEventStatePressed";
            case ToneEventStateReleased:
                return @"ToneEventStateReleased";
            default:
                return @"null";
        }
    }
```

`showPark` is called from a method not shown previously so I'll include it here.

```
- (void)sendMIDIEvent:(uint8_t)midiStatus
                data1:(uint8_t)mapped_MIDINoteNumber    // dekany buttons mapped to MIDI Note Numbers 0-9
                data2:(uint8_t)data2
    {
        // 1. check parking bay

    [self showPark:(uint8_t)midiStatus data1:(uint8_t)mapped_MIDINoteNumber];

        // 2. identify MIDI status

    if (midiStatus  == MIDI_Status_KeyOn_RissetChorus)  // 144

    {
        // 3. pick up duration and send a message to playChorus

        [self   playChorus:(uint8_t)midiStatus
               chorusPitch:(uint8_t)mapped_MIDINoteNumber
                    length:(int)noteLength];
        }  
        else
        {

        if (midiStatus  == MIDI_Status_KeyOn_RissetBell)    // 145

        {
        // 4. pick up duration and send a message to playBell

        [self playBell:(uint8_t)midiStatus
             bellPitch:(uint8_t)mapped_MIDINoteNumber
                length:(int)noteLength];
        }
    }
}
```

---

**playBell**

```
-(void)playBell:(uint8_t)midiStatus
  bellPitch:(uint8_t)midiNoteNumber
     length:(int)length;
{
    hasPitchEnvelope                        = FALSE;

    for (int n = 0; n < MaxToneEvents; ++n)
    {
        if (_tones[n].state == ToneEventStateInactive)          // find an empty slot
        {
            _tones[n].state                 = ToneEventStatePressed;

            _tones[n].frequency             = _pitches[midiNoteNumber];

            _tones[n].phase1                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase2                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase3                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase4                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase5                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase6                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase7                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase8                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase9                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase10               = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase11               = 0.0f;

            _tones[n].levelEnvelope1        = _levelPartialEnvelope1;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope2        = _levelPartialEnvelope2;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope3        = _levelPartialEnvelope3;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope4        = _levelPartialEnvelope4;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope5        = _levelPartialEnvelope5;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope6        = _levelPartialEnvelope6;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope7        = _levelPartialEnvelope7;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope8        = _levelPartialEnvelope8;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope9        = _levelPartialEnvelope9;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope10       = _levelPartialEnvelope10;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope11       = _levelPartialEnvelope11;

            _tones[n].gain                  = 1.0f;
            _tones[n].envStep               = 0.0f;            
            _tones[n].envDelta              = ENVELOPE_LENGTH / length;     // GS Envelope
            _tones[n].fadeOut               = 1.0f;

            return;
        }
    }
}
```

---

**playChorus**

```
- (void)playChorus:(uint8_t)midiStatus
   chorusPitch:(uint8_t)midiNoteNumber
        length:(int)length;
{
    hasPitchEnvelope                            = TRUE;

   for (int n = 0; n < MaxToneEvents; ++n)
   {
        if (_tones[n].state == ToneEventStateInactive)          // find an empty slot
        {
            _tones[n].state                 = ToneEventStatePressed;

            _tones[n].frequency             = _pitches[midiNoteNumber];

            _tones[n].phase1                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase2                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase3                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase4                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase5                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase6                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase7                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase8                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase9                = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase10               = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].phase11               = 0.0f;

            _tones[n].levelEnvelope1        = _levelEnvelopeAboveOuter;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope2        = _levelEnvelopeAboveInner;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope3        = _levelEnvelopeCentreNote;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope4        = _levelEnvelopeBelowInner;
            _tones[n].levelEnvelope5        = _levelEnvelopeBelowOuter;

            _tones[n].pitchEnvelope1        = _pitchEnvelopeAboveOuter;
            _tones[n].pitchEnvelope2        = _pitchEnvelopeAboveInner;
            _tones[n].pitchEnvelope3        = _pitchEnvelopeCentreNote;
            _tones[n].pitchEnvelope4        = _pitchEnvelopeBelowInner;
            _tones[n].pitchEnvelope5        = _pitchEnvelopeBelowOuter;

            _tones[n].gain                  = 1.0f;
            _tones[n].envStep               = 0.0f;
            _tones[n].envDelta              = ENVELOPE_LENGTH / length;     // GS Envelope
            _tones[n].fadeOut               = 1.0f;

        return;
    }
}
}
```

---

**ToneEvent**

```
typedef enum
{
    ToneEventStateInactive = 0,         // ToneEvent is not used for playing a tone
    ToneEventStatePressed,              // ToneEvent is still playing normally
    ToneEventStateReleased,             // ToneEvent is released and ringing out
}
ToneEventState;
```

---

***bell crash***

```
2017-07-28 21:05:28.438 SatGam2[897:503237] ENABLED (player 4: state 1)
2017-07-28 21:05:28.502804+1000 SatGam2[897:504929] [aqme] 254:     AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0
2017-07-28 21:05:30.511372+1000 SatGam2[897:504929] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0
2017-07-28 21:05:30.852 SatGam2[897:503237]  ToneEventStatePressed
2017-07-28 21:05:30.853 SatGam2[897:503237] ToneEventStateReleased
2017-07-28 21:05:30.853 SatGam2[897:503237]  ToneEventStatePressed
2017-07-28 21:05:30.854 SatGam2[897:503237]  ToneEventStatePressed
2017-07-28 21:05:30.854 SatGam2[897:503237]  ToneEventStatePressed
2017-07-28 21:05:30.854 SatGam2[897:503237] noteLength 70
2017-07-28 21:05:30.855 SatGam2[897:503237] timeToGo 70 [RissetBells, from PlayViewController]
2017-07-28 21:05:30.855 SatGam2[897:503237] Risset Bell MIDI note number 1 : length 70
2017-07-28 21:05:30.855 SatGam2[897:503237] Clapper button 7 pressed
SatGam2 was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
(lldb) bt
* thread #10, name = 'com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0x9514)
  * frame #0: 0x00071d82 SatGam2`-[Synth amplitudeLookupPartial6:](self=<unavailable>, _cmd="amplitudeLookupPartial6:", n=<unavailable>) at Synth.m:875 [opt]
frame #1: 0x000713f6 SatGam2`-[Synth fillBuffer:frames:](self=0x7e805a00, _cmd="fillBuffer:frames:", buffer=<unavailable>, frames=<unavailable>) at Synth.m:692 [opt]
frame #2: 0x000751e9 SatGam2`__39-[PlayViewController startAudioSession]_block_invoke((null)=0x7ae48160, buffer=<unavailable>, audioFormat=AudioStreamBasicDescription @ 0xb0491ab8) at PlayViewController.m:393 [opt]
frame #3: 0x00073985 SatGam2`PlayCallback(inUserData=0x7c44ac60, inAudioQueue=<unavailable>, inBuffer=<unavailable>) at AudioBufferPlayer.m:30 [opt]
frame #4: 0x00a65e90 AudioToolbox`ClientAudioQueue::CallOutputCallback(AudioQueueBuffer*) + 336
frame #5: 0x00a69a99 AudioToolbox`ClientMessageHandler::OutputBufferComplete(unsigned int) + 137
frame #6: 0x00a5fc90 AudioToolbox`AQClientCallbackMessageReader::DispatchCallbacks(void const*, unsigned long) + 176
frame #7: 0x00a5f98d AudioToolbox`ClientAudioQueue::FetchAndDeliverPendingCallbacks(unsigned int) + 301
frame #8: 0x00a5fb78 AudioToolbox`AQCallbackReceiver_CallbackNotificationsAvailable + 152
frame #9: 0x009b071a AudioToolbox`_XCallbackNotificationsAvailable + 42
frame #10: 0x00c3b37b AudioToolbox`mshMIGPerform + 207
frame #11: 0x035e28b3 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
frame #12: 0x035e2822 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 498
frame #13: 0x035daccd CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2669
frame #14: 0x035d9fd4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 372
frame #15: 0x035d9e4b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #16: 0x00a6a822 AudioToolbox`GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 178
frame #17: 0x00c406b2 AudioToolbox`CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 96
frame #18: 0x06215047 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 184
frame #19: 0x06214f8f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 243
frame #20: 0x0621484a libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 34
(lldb)
```

---

***chorus crash***

```
2017-07-28 20:30:13.061 SatGam2[864:436890] ENABLED (player 4: state 2)
2017-07-28 20:30:13.227994+1000 SatGam2[864:438359] [aqme] 254: AQDefaultDevice (173): skipping input stream 0 0 0x0
2017-07-28 20:30:14.878 SatGam2[864:436890]  ToneEventStatePressed
2017-07-28 20:30:14.878 SatGam2[864:436890] ToneEventStateReleased
2017-07-28 20:30:14.879 SatGam2[864:436890]  ToneEventStatePressed
2017-07-28 20:30:14.879 SatGam2[864:436890]  ToneEventStatePressed
2017-07-28 20:30:14.879 SatGam2[864:436890]  ToneEventStatePressed
2017-07-28 20:30:14.879 SatGam2[864:436890] noteLength 47
2017-07-28 20:30:14.880 SatGam2[864:436890] timeToGo 47 [RissetChorus, from PlayViewController]
2017-07-28 20:30:14.880 SatGam2[864:436890] Risset Chorus MIDI note number 3 : length 47
2017-07-28 20:30:14.880 SatGam2[864:436890] Note button 4 pressed
SatGam2 was compiled with optimization - stepping may behave oddly; variables may not be available.
(lldb) bt
* thread #10, name = 'com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS (code=1, address=0xe62c)
  * frame #0: 0x0007b728 SatGam2`-[Synth pitchShiftLookupPartial1:](self=0x7bb0d400, _cmd="pitchShiftLookupPartial1:", n=0) at Synth.m:762 [opt]
frame #1: 0x0007aeb6 SatGam2`-[Synth fillBuffer:frames:](self=0x7bb0d400, _cmd="fillBuffer:frames:", buffer=<unavailable>, frames=<unavailable>) at Synth.m:724 [opt]
frame #2: 0x0007f1e9 SatGam2`__39-[PlayViewController startAudioSession]_block_invoke((null)=0x7c74d5b0, buffer=<unavailable>, audioFormat=AudioStreamBasicDescription @ 0xb01f9ab8) at PlayViewController.m:393 [opt]
frame #3: 0x0007d985 SatGam2`PlayCallback(inUserData=0x7b656430, inAudioQueue=<unavailable>, inBuffer=<unavailable>) at AudioBufferPlayer.m:30 [opt]
frame #4: 0x00a14e90 AudioToolbox`ClientAudioQueue::CallOutputCallback(AudioQueueBuffer*) + 336
frame #5: 0x00a18a99 AudioToolbox`ClientMessageHandler::OutputBufferComplete(unsigned int) + 137
frame #6: 0x00a0ec90 AudioToolbox`AQClientCallbackMessageReader::DispatchCallbacks(void const*, unsigned long) + 176
frame #7: 0x00a0e98d AudioToolbox`ClientAudioQueue::FetchAndDeliverPendingCallbacks(unsigned int) + 301
frame #8: 0x00a0eb78 AudioToolbox`AQCallbackReceiver_CallbackNotificationsAvailable + 152
frame #9: 0x0095f71a AudioToolbox`_XCallbackNotificationsAvailable + 42
frame #10: 0x00bea37b AudioToolbox`mshMIGPerform + 207
frame #11: 0x035988b3 CoreFoundation`__CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_SOURCE1_PERFORM_FUNCTION__ + 35
frame #12: 0x03598822 CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopDoSource1 + 498
frame #13: 0x03590ccd CoreFoundation`__CFRunLoopRun + 2669
frame #14: 0x0358ffd4 CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 372
frame #15: 0x0358fe4b CoreFoundation`CFRunLoopRunInMode + 123
frame #16: 0x00a19822 AudioToolbox`GenericRunLoopThread::Entry(void*) + 178
frame #17: 0x00bef6b2 AudioToolbox`CAPThread::Entry(CAPThread*) + 96
frame #18: 0x0621f047 libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_body + 184
frame #19: 0x0621ef8f libsystem_pthread.dylib`_pthread_start + 243
frame #20: 0x0621e84a libsystem_pthread.dylib`thread_start + 34
(lldb)
```

Comment: Please read [Under what circumstances may I add “urgent” or other similar phrases to my question, in order to obtain faster answers?](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/326569) - the summary is that this is not an ideal way to address volunteers, and is probably counterproductive to obtaining answers. Please refrain from adding this to your questions.

Comment: I would not recommend relying on Stack Overflow if you have a hard deadline - perhaps bringing in a contractor for a couple of hours for one-on-one support is what you need?

Comment: halfer, thanks for the link and the edit. In future this is something I will keep in mind.

Comment: You said a previous version worked before; question is what did you change with this newer version?

Comment: @halfer, if it is of interest I added a method to log the problem more clearly

Comment: Have you searched the web for `com.apple.coreaudio.AQClient', stop reason = EXC_BAD_ACCESS`? I don't use iOS, but that sounds like a low-level bug that would need Apple's attention.